# Efficiently renaming dataframe columns with complex logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have two issues here is the first one I want to `concat` `sheets` on `xlsx` for the below code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS = r'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx'
sheet_names = ['client31_KPN', 'client32_T-Mobile', 'client33_Vodafone']
cols = ['A:AB', 'A:AB', 'A:AB']
df = {}
for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, cols):
    df[ws] = pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name = ws, usecols = c)
```

the second issue I want to read all columns in the sheet instead using the below line:

```
cols = ['A:AB', 'A:AB', 'A:AB']
```

Note that:
the columns in the sheets with the same names

as also I want to perform a code as the below with better and shorter way:

```
# shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns)
dataframes2 = [shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3]
join2 = pd.concat(dataframes2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

and the previous code is belong to my old code before updating as the below one:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS = 'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx'

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS), sheet_name='client31_KPN')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS), sheet_name='client32_T-Mobile')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS), sheet_name='client33_Vodafone')

#shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1.columns)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2.columns)

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns = map(str.lower, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3.columns)
dataframes2 = [shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df1, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df2, shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS_df3]
join2 = pd.concat(dataframes2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#Edited:

I tried to create something to near what I want as the below code:

```
for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, cols):
    df[ws] = pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name = ws, usecols = c)

    df[ws].columns = df[ws].columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
    df[ws].columns = df[ws].columns.str.replace('\n', '')
    df[ws].columns = df[ws].columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
    df[ws].columns = map(str.lower, df[ws].columns)

    join2 = pd.concat(ws).reset_index(drop=True)
```

but I found the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python Projects/MyAuditPy/pd_read.py", line 29, in <module>
    join2 = pd.concat(ws).reset_index(drop=True)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 271, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 306, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "str"
```

Comment: This is more of a "Code Review". There is a more specific website for that, but you can do things like `str.replace(['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'], regex=True).map(...)`

Comment: @DavidErickson thanks for your suggestion I have just post the answer could you check please may you have how to better perform this code

Comment: Honestly, the question could be a bit more focused and is too confusing. Also, it is not a minimum reproducible example with input and expected output for the data. It looks like someone was kind enough to look at your code and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I try to avoid assigning the `.columns` attribute directly. Too much risk in getting things wrong.

Here's what I would do:

```py
def renamer(c):
    # I'm assuming this does what you want. hard to tell without knowing
    # what your input and output looks like.
    return (
        c.strip().split(' ')[-1].lower()
    )

df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name=ws, usecols=c)
      .rename(columns=renamer)
    for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, cols)
], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have a question do I have to rename all columns one bye one? I have more than 100 of columns :d

Comment: I don't need to create a dictionary

Comment: @MahmoudHarooney you don't need a dictionary and one is not created in this answer. The `.rename` method maps the passed function to all of the columns names.

Comment: about this part `.rename(columns=renamer)` what the renamer refers to?

Comment: @MahmoudHarooney whoops. there's a typo in my answer. I meant to call the function I define at the top `renamer`, not `renames`. I've corrected that.

Comment: wow that's brilliant bro :D best answer I got thanks alot you saved my time :D... I got the idea now :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok Good I think I may have solved it like the below code and it works fine:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS = r'Shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.xlsx'

sheet_names = ['client31_KPN', 'client32_T-Mobile', 'client33_Vodafone']
cols = ['A:AB', 'A:AB', 'A:AB']

df = {}

for ws, c in zip(sheet_names, cols):
    df[ws] = pd.read_excel(shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS, sheet_name = ws, usecols = c)

    df[ws].columns = df[ws].columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
    df[ws].columns = df[ws].columns.str.replace('\n', '')
    df[ws].columns = df[ws].columns.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "")
    df[ws].columns = map(str.lower, df[ws].columns)

    join2 = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
join2.to_csv("shared_BM_NL_Q2_DNS.csv")
```

Please give me some suggestions